# Django url pattern is not a registered view function or pattern

Tags: python, html, django, django-urls

I have a small Django web app, with multiple applications inside them. I have used the include in the **urls.py** files, but whenever I reference the **URLs** in the HTML files they don't load. Below are my **3 urls.py** files. The one I'm having an issue will specifically is the nodes url pattern in the nodes **urls.py**

```
#main urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
    
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
]

#account urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('nodes/', include('nodes.urls')),
]


#nodes urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'nodes'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.nodes, name='nodes'),
]
```

This is my HTML file where I am referencing the URL pattern:

```
<li {% if section == 'nodes' %}class="active"{% endif %}>
     <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'nodes' %}">Nodes</a>
</li>
```

Comment: You can try without the " " brackets. Just go with <a href={% url 'index' %}>Начало</a>

Comment: you aren't including your node urls in main urls file

Comment: @Henty how would I do that? I thought because the account urls.py is included in the main urls.py file then nodes urls.py file would be included?

Comment: oh yeah i missed that sorry, i think it would be something like 'account.nodes.nodes' or a shorter version to call it

Comment: @Henty where would I put this?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with not including the nodes urls in the main file.

Comment: What do you have in your error log? And also do you have the nodes app in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: @IvanDimitrov yes that what I thought, I also have the same problem with the dashboard in the account urls.py

Comment: @IvanDimitrov This is the error I get: Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: @Morgan and dashboard is not a class base view? If it is you should include .as_view()

Comment: @IvanDimitrov yes it is a class based view

Comment: I have fixed the issue with the dashboard and nodes, but now I have a problem with the login url pattern

Comment: @IvanDimitrov the html file says it has an error at line 0, which is confusing as there is no line 0

Comment: and what does the error log say? I think the problem is with the login view itself.

Answer (score 1):

Due to this pattern name you set in `urls file` if change HTML file to this it must be fixed:

```
<li {% if section == 'nodes' %}class="active"{% endif %}>
   <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account:nodes:nodes' %}">Nodes</a>
</li>
```

just for tips :) if import urls file at the django shell and print list of `urlspatterns` you could see default name assign to your `nodes` path.

Comment: will I also have to change this in the settings.py at the LOGIN_URL attribute?

Comment: @Morgan __LOGIN_URL__ just the URL or named URL pattern where requests are redirected for login when using the `login_required()` decorator, this settings variable not related to your `Django reverse path` used at Django template tags, But if you use named URL these names must be the same.

Comment: @Morgan Did not my answer to solve your problem ? I was test your code at empty Django project and direct path correctly to nodes view. If you still have an error please edit your question with error logs

Comment: Yes it did thank you @Erfan, I was still having problems, but then I found one line of html which I hadn't changed and now its fixed. Thank you